# Не работает javascript в документе, вызванным AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, через AJAX в странице 1 получаю страницу 2.
В странице 2 находится код image cropper .
Когда отдельно открываю 2 страницу, image cropper работает, а когда с помощью AJAX показываю, не работает . В чем может быть проблема ?

Вот код :

> страница 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#keyword3").keyup(function(){
     var search = $("#keyword3").val();
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "2.php",
       data: {"keyword3": search},
       cache: false,                                 
       success: function(response){
          $("#resSearch3").html(response);
       }
     });
     return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

> Страница 2

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    Event.observe ( 
        window, 
        'load', 
        function() { 
            new Cropper.Img ( 
                't3soeta',
                {
                    minWidth: 200, 
                    minHeight: 250,
                    ratioDim: { x: 200, y: 250 },
                    displayOnInit: true, 
                    onEndCrop: saveCoords,
                    onloadCoords: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 200, y2: 250 },
                }
            ) 
        }
    );

    function saveCoords (coords, dimensions)
    {
        $( 'x1' ).value = coords.x1;
        $( 'y1' ).value = coords.y1;
        $( 'width' ).value = dimensions.width;
        $( 'height' ).value = dimensions.height;
    }
    </script>


    <form action="saveCrop.php" method="post">
        <h2>Image Cropping Tutorial (Without Preview)</h2>
        <div>
            <img src="../../images/lapsi.jpg" id="t3soeta" alt="New T3 Soeta" />
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="x1" id="x1" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="y1" id="y1" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="width" id="width" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="height" id="height" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="Done" value=" Done ">
    </form>
```

Comment: Конечно работать не будет, после загрузки страницы 2, в success: function(response){ } вам надо ещё раз необходимо инициализировать функцию Cropper

Comment: И как это сделать Арсен?

Comment: Я же написал как сделать,   после загрузки страницы 2, в success: function(response){   } вам надо ещё раз необходимо инициализировать функцию Cropper

Comment: В этом и проблема) я новичок, код нашел в интернете.
Если не трудно можете показать как это пишется?)

Comment: Вы это имели виду?

 success: function(response){
          $("#resSearch3").html(response); 
    
 Event.observe (
    window,
    'load',
    function() {
    new Cropper.Img (
    't3soeta',
    {
    minWidth: 200,
    minHeight: 250,
    ratioDim: { x: 200, y: 250 },
    displayOnInit: true,
    onEndCrop: saveCoords,
    onloadCoords: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 200, y2: 250 },
    }
    )
    }
    );    
       }
     });
     return false;
   });
});
</script>

Comment: Все равно не хочет работать